# Онлайн сервис для сжатия css js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Так как с php я не дружу, подскажите сервис пожалуйста. И насколько это хуже gzip? Спасибо!

Comment: [Closure Compiler Service UI](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_ui?csw=1)

Comment: @Deonis это только для js? Спасибо!

Comment: @АлександрАлексеев https://cssminifier.com

Answer (score 3):

> это только для js?

А для CSS, чего там особо сжимать? Убрать пробелы, переносы строк, да и последнюю точку с запятой в секции. Это на любом ЯП - пара строк кода. Если с PHP не дружите, то на JS можно реализовать. Вот простенький пример:

```js
start.addEventListener('click', function(){
 output.value = input.value.replace(/[\s\n]/g, '').replace(/;\}/g, '}');
}, false);
```

```css
textarea {
    width: 45%;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input">
.class {
    background-color: #900;
    font-size: 2em;
}
#id {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    color: #060;
}
</textarea>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
<br>
<button id="start">Start</button>
```

Comment: "для CSS, чего там особо сжимать?" это щас модно. наворотить тыщу пицот стилей,  а потом париться. работает процессор или нет - но сжать надо !

Comment: Хороший пример, но минификация предполагает не только репарсинг

Answer (score 1):

gzip и минификация это две операции хорошо дополняющие друг друга.

gzip выполняет архивирование ответа от сервера, который разархивирует браузер при получении (уменьшение размера может достигать различных значений в зависимости от исходной информации, например, файл 3д модели в формате *.obj можно сжать практически на 60%). Веб сервер можно настроить на сжатие чего угодно, даже картинок (просто сжатие изображений не имеет смысла).

При минификации удаляются переносы строк, комментарии, и выполняется прочая оптимизация (например в js для краткости переименовываются локальные переменные).

Онлайн сервис посоветовать не могу, но предлагаю обратить внимание на nodejs
В npm доступны различные модули, в число которых входит и минификация. Вы можете установить grunt или gulp и создать задачу минификации перед релизом вашего сайта. Например, посмотрите [этот плагин для js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) и [этот для css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglifycss)

Так же существует минификация статических html файлов.

Для visual studio доступно расширение [Bundler & Minifier](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ec27da7-e24b-4d56-8064-fd7e88ac1c40)

Comment: >gzip и минификация

Answer (score 1):

Гуглится достаточно просто по `online js minifier` `online css minifier`:

[Онлайн сервис для минификации JavaScript](https://jscompress.com/), [ещё один](https://javascript-minifier.com/).

[Онлайн сервис для минификации CSS](https://cssminifier.com/)

На практике, каждый раз после модификации исходных файлов, выполнять минификацию вручную не удобно. Один из распространенных вариантов - использовать системы сборки (вроде [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)) и плагины к ним, которые будут выполнять рутинную работу.

`gzip` может быть дополнением к минификации, т.к. одно другому не мешает (разве что сжимаются минифицированные файлы немного хуже, т.к. они уже очищены от повторяющихся пробелов и т.д.).